# Google Chrome Extension like Sublime Text 2 Minimap Scrollbar?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, sublime-text-2

Is there an Google Chrome extension that adds a minimap next to the scroll bar like Sublime Text 2?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This might be worth looking into.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/minimap/opcbonhbaamhjmlbcedangecgjjiollh

Comment: Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/minimap-scroller-sidebar/

Answer (score 0):

eLife Lens has a [Document Map](http://lens.elifesciences.org/about/#figures/paragraph_15/figure_2) in HTML5.